# What's the limit of BONITA Platform ? Can a Business Analyst generate a whole Java Web App with just pre-programmed connectors?

Tags: java

I'm studying some systems that allow faster App dev cycles. So I stumbled upon BONITA. It seems that by preparing some connectors you can allow a Business to generate a whole App.

What's the limit of Bonita and what is needed to improve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonita is one of probably many Business Process tools. Like all such tools there are good and bad things. Yes they allow some business processes to be automated by users by dragging and dropping components, or process steps in some sort of GUI. And like systems, say SAP for example, if you fight precisely in the SAP box it can get you going much faster and easier. I've never met any business that fit "exactly" in the SAP box though, and usually there are years spent customizing it. In my experience, the users usually give up on this after a while and want developers to do this for them when they experience something that doesn't quite do what they thought it would. The developers try it out, become frustrated with the limitations or just get overwhelmed by NIH syndrome, and the tool is soon abandoned. Alternatively, and perhaps more concerning, is when you get the true user enthusiast that quite innocently takes down a production database in the middle of the day trying to look at their data in new ways, but without training wheels.
YMMV

Comment: Thank you that is a thorough insight. 

I don't think such tools is for users as it still requires some technical background. That's why I'm talking about a Business Analyst who for the ones I know often come from IT and did migrate to Business.

Comment: I understand Developers get frustrated because they don't feel at ease with Black Box thinking. But that the inverse for a true Business Analyst or a Functional Software Architect so if Bonita is pluggable enough like Eclipse by analogy one should be able to use it as a usable platform.

Comment: Much like a dev should/would have a test environment, a power user should have one too for new process building so that errant workflows cannot "take down a production database".

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm evaluating Bonita Open Solution (BOS) for internal use in small company and I think it's a great platform to build workflow applications on. I believe that a manager having basic BPM knowledge can quite easily prototype the whole process including user interaction forms, some of process variables and condition on flows, and simulate anytime with one click. Since you're modelling application, you can completely reorganize the flow when optimizing process. Anytime a programmer can come and implement interactions with external services using connector, again not a hard thing.  Once you are ready, just export application and deploy on server.

Bonita has simple but powerful Java API. Accessing it you can tweak most limitations.

Nice thing about Bonita is it's active development. Also forum is quite supportive and even the developers of BOS answer the questions in a short time (hours or few days on weekends).